# Would it be correct to state that all the forms of everyday matter (mountains, tables, buildings, people, etc.) are in a metastable state?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, stability, combustion

We had a fire going in the backyard of a friends house this weekend, and after thinking about the chemical reactions occurring in the wood (and anything else we threw into the pit), I started to wonder if everyday (stable) arrangements of matter wouldn't be more aptly described as metastable. Especially when considering that anything from wood to stone to metal will burn if hot enough.

After all, isn't the charred wood simply an indication that the atomic/molecular arrangement has undergone an energetically favorable change to a lower energy state?

Not sure if I'm misapplying the term, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is correct. The universe hasn't reached its thermodynamic ground state, yet. What would that be? We don't know, but based on what we know, it would essentially be empty space filled with nothing but light.

Comment: Meta-stability is a matter of time-scale. Sure, you can take the arbitrarily long view and say it, but beware: as a factoid devoid of information about that time scale it is just [the kind of "I love science" nonsense that happiness and cyanide spoof as posterior ogling](http://explosm.net/comics/3557/). For a more serious application (though rather dated now), see [Dyson's paper "Time Without End"](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.447)  (or in [plain text](http://www.aleph.se/Trans/Global/Omega/dyson.txt) if you can't get past the paywall).

Comment: It's true of *most* everyday objects, but not all. The water in my glass is thermodynamically stable...

Comment: @lemon Read the Dyson paper for the view over *very* long time-scales.

Comment: @dmckee One sentence summary? ... In this context metastability is defined to be a state with a local free energy minimum, so I don't see how time-scale is relevant.

Comment: Well, I can't summarize the whole paper but on timescales orders of magnitude longer than the current age of the universe those nuclei are unstable to tunneling fusion. That's what I mean by time-scale mattering.